# grep / awk / perl / sed - print all lines that match X, ignore lines that only have YX and include lines that have YX ZX

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, grep

I have a file (tmp.txt) that looks like:

```
 first
 first rst
 allrst
```

printf "first\nfirst rst\nallrst\n" > tmp.txt;

And I want:

```
 first rst
 allrst
```

Is there any way to search for 'rst', but exclude the match if rst is only found in first?

I've tried:

```
awk '(/rst/ && /first/) || (/rst/ && !/first/)' tmp.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` without `-P` option:

```
grep 'rst' file | grep -v '^first$'
first rst
allrst
```

Using `grep -P`

```
grep -P '^(?!first$).*rst' file
first rst
allrst
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=.*(?<!fi)rst).*$
```

Try this in Perl.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kP8uF5/13

Answer (score 0):

or a variation from vks's answer

```
^(.*(?<!fi)rst.*)$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kP8uF5/14)

```
^               Start of string
(               Capturing Group \1
  .             Any character except line break
  *             (zero or more)(greedy)
  (?<!          Negative Look-Behind
    fi          "fi"
  )             End of Negative Look-Behind
  rst           "rst"
  .             Any character except line break
  *             (zero or more)(greedy)
)               End of Capturing Group \1
$               End of string
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex in Perl would be `/^.*(?<!fi)rst.*/m`

```
 ^ .* 
 (?<! fi )
 rst .*
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't define that, the `rst` must be at the end of the line, so this may work for your requirement:

```
grep -P '(?<!fi)rst' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'h;s/first//g;/rst/!d;g' file
```

Make a copy of the current line. Remove all `first`'s and check the remaining line for `rst`. If the string is in the altered line print the copy otherwise delete the line.

Answer (score 0):

This meets all your requirements:

```
perl -ne 'print if /^(?=.*first)(?=.*(?<!fi)rst)/; next if /first/; print if /rst/'
```

1. line has "first" and a non-first "rst": print it
2. line has "first": skip it
3. line has "rst": print it

Or, as your title suggest, symbolically

```
perl -ne '
  BEGIN {$x="rst"; $y="fi"; $z="(?<!fi)"}
  print if /^(?=.*$y$x)(?=.*$z$x)/; next if /$y$x/; print if /$x/
'
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the pattern is not specified precisely. What should be done if the line contains `afirst` or `rstfirst`? So I created two versions. I assume that each row contains the string `rst`. Which not, it does not need to be printed. I prefer [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) solution against [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) as the later uses much more resources to start and it is not really needed for this task.

The first version checks all words containing `rst`, but not equal to `first`. If one if found, the row is printed.

```
awk '/rst/ {
  for(i=1;i<=NF&&$i~/rst/&&$i=="first";++i);
}i<=NF' inputfile
```

Input file:

```
first
first rst
allrst
afirst
rstfirst
```

Ouput:

```
first rst
allrst
afirst
rstfirst
```

The other solution check for all `rst` and then adds the previous two characters (if applicable). If the result string is not `first` then it prints the line. (Similar to `sln`'s negative look-behind buffer [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) solution )

```
awk '/rst/ {
  for(s=$0;i=index(s,"rst");s=substr(s,i+1)) 
    if (i<2 || substr(s,i-2,5)!="first") {print; break}
}' inputfile
```

Output:

```
first rst
allrst
rstfirst
```

I hope this helps a bit!

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '1!{/rst/p}' tmp.txt
```

If not on the first line, print a match with the pattern rst in the line or if you want to count rst yet not in first alone - only if rst is also in another string:

```
sed -n '/[^f][^i]rst/p' tmp.txt
```

Or if you want to use a Bash shell, you can be more flexible with similar requirements:

```
while read -r a; do  
 num_first=$(echo "$a" | grep -c 'first');
 num_rst=$(echo "$a" | sed 's/first//g' | grep -c 'rst'); 
 if [[ $num_rst+1 -gt $num_first ]]; then 
   echo "$a"; 
 fi done < tmp.txt
```

This code uses grep to count first and then rst - only if rst is in more than the string first will it print the string.

As a one-liner:

`while read -r a; do num_first=$(echo "$a" | grep -c 'first');num_rst=$(echo "$a" | sed 's/first//g' | grep -c 'rst'); if [[ $num_rst+1 -gt $num_first ]]; then echo "$a"; fi done < myfile`